# How to trim multiple characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, trim

I have a string as follows

```
const example = ' ( some string ()() here )   ';
```

If I trim the string with

```
example.trim()
```

it will give me the output: `( some string ()() here )`

But I want the output `some string ()() here`. How to achieve that?

```js
const example = ' ( some string ()() here )   ';
console.log(example.trim());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regex for leading and trailing space/brackets:

```
/^\s+\(\s+(.*)\s+\)\s+$/g
```

```js
function grabText(str) { 
  return str.replace(/^\s+\(\s+(.*)\s+\)\s+$/g,"$1");
}

var strings = [
  '  ( some (string) here )   ',
  ' ( some string ()() here )   '];
  
strings.forEach(function(str) {
  console.log('>'+str+'<')
  console.log('>'+grabText(str)+'<')
  console.log('-------')
})
```

If the strings are optionally leading and/or trailing, you need to create some optional non-capturing groups

```
/^(?:\s+\(\s+?)?(.*?)(?:\s+\)\s+?)?$/g
/^ - from start
  (?:\s+\(\s+?)? - 0 or more non-capturing occurrences of  ' ( '
                (.*?) - this is the text we want
                     (?:\s+\)\s+?)? - 0 or more non-capturing occurrences of  ' ) '
                                  $/ - till end
                                    g - global flag is not really used here
```

```js
function grabText(str) {
  return str.replace(/^(?:\s+\(\s+?)?(.*?)(?:\s+\)\s+?)?$/g, "$1");
}

strings = ['some (trailing) here )   ',
           ' ( some embedded () plus leading and trailing brakets here )   ',
           ' ( some leading and embedded ()() here'
];
strings.forEach(function(str) {
  console.log('>' + str + '<')
  console.log('>' + grabText(str) + '<')
  console.log('-------')
})
```

Comment: thanks for this, but this is a bad assumption. the string inside can also contain `()`. That's why I'm trying to trim. Just updated my question to have better clarity. Sorry about that

Comment: Well, by definition `trim` only removes whitespace. Occasionally you'd find some trim functionality that does more - actually the other day I found out C# does that, where you can define which characters to remove from the beginning and the end but the generally understood definition of trim is for whitespace only.

Comment: Please see my updated example which includes inner brackets

Comment: @vlaz definitely! C# has that. That's why I was wondering if I can do that in JS too. But apparently I need to use regex and replace

Comment: Well, you can write your own function that does it without regex: take parameters for what to strip, go from the beginning and end of the string and skip any strippable character, then return the inner part. But it'd be a bit of a wasted effort, as regex+replace is readily available.

Comment: @sertsedat - my latest version handles both your cases

Comment: @vlaz well yeah, I would prefer a built-in function rather than creating my own.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the regex to get the matched string, The below regex, matches the first character followed by characters or whitespaces and ending with a alphanumberic character

```js
const example = ' ( some (string) ()()here )   ';
console.log(example.match(/(\w[\w\s.(.*)]+)\w/g));
```

Comment: @mplungjan, yes that won't work. Ahh, OP updates his question

Comment: well this also works. sorry about that. I guess you didn't see edited question. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove only the outer brackets after the trim you can use

```js
var input = ' ( some string ()() here )   '.trim();
if( input.charAt(0) == '(' && input.charAt(input.length-1) == ')') {

var result = input.slice(1, -1).trim()
 console.log(result)
}
```

Last trim is optional which removes the space between `(` and `s` also between `e` and `)`

Comment: well, this is another possible way of course, but I get the string from an API and the spaces and parentheses are not always there. If I knew for sure then I would just use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const str = ' ( some ( string ) here ) '.replace(/^\s+\(\s+(.*)\s+\)\s+$/g,'$1');
 console.log(str);
```

Comment: Why trim after using a regex? You can let the regex do the trim too

Comment: yes yes :) I was writing an other solution so it is fixed now

Comment: Your solution is now identical to mine - exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive method and specify the number of times you wish to trim the string. This will also work with things other than round brackets, for instance, square brackets:

```js
const example = ' ( some string ()() here )   ';
const exampleTwo = ' [  This, is [some] text    ]   ';

function trim_factor(str, times) {
  if(times == 0) {
    return str;
  }
  str = str.trim();
  return str.charAt(0) + trim_factor(str.substr(1, str.length-2), times-1) + str.charAt(str.length-1);
}

console.log(trim_factor(example, 2));
console.log(trim_factor(exampleTwo, 2));
```